# Toric Bézier patches

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, toric-varieties

Toric Bézier patches (as described in https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2116) are maps from a lattice polytope $P$ to the positive part of its associated toric variety $X_P$. While they are not the inverse of the algebraic moment map, which is a natural map $X_P \to P$, they have interesting properties such as being an homeomorphism of manifolds with corners.

I would like to understand what is known about how toric patches glue together. For example, suppose that a polytope $P$ is decomposed as $P=\bigcup_i P_i$, how do the different Bezier patches interact among themselves and with the "global" one associated to $P$?